# Save File to Directory when locked screen or Logged out

Tags: python, directory, save, pyautogui

Trying to save a file to a directory using python, selenium, and PyAutoGui. It works as intended when the user is logged in. The problem occurs when I'm trying to automate the script. If I use task scheduler or create the script into a windows service, the script doesn't open the browser. This won't work with selenium because it needs to access the browser on the desktop to work. The work around I found was using task scheduler with the user logged in. Selenium works as intended.

The problem with this approach is that the computer has to always remain on. Locking the screen allows the script to run, but the file doesn't save into the directory as intended.

Stuck and can't think of a better work around.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please read [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask) as well as take the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Show me how to solve this coding problem" [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You have to [make an honest attempt at the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a specific question about your implementation.